# Если нет пользователя в базе данных, то добавить его. Если он есть, то продолжить код

Tags: python, mysql, sql, telegram, telebot

Здравия! Не могу разобраться. Делаю бота-анкету с telebot, он должен при /start добавлять айди телеги юзера в базу данных. Если ещё раз написать /start и если юзер уже есть в базе, то вывести сообщение "Вы вернулись!", если юзера нет в базе данных, то написать "Вас нет в базе :("

Пытался сделать так, но он всё равно не хочет работать так, как надо.

```
def firstSeen(get_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    db_worker = conn.cursor()
    db_worker.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=?", (get_id,))
    rez = db_worker.fetchall()

    if not rez:
        print('Добавил в базу')
        return addUser(get_id)
    else:
        print('Уже в базе')


def addUser(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    db_worker = conn.cursor()
    db_worker.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES ({},'{}')".format(message, "true"))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def on_start(message):
    if firstSeen(message.chat.id) == message.chat.id:
        print('--- Вы вернулись!')
    else:
        print('=== Вас нет в базе')
```

С кодом выше он выводит вот что:
Уже в базе
=== Вас нет в базе

Comment: `if firstSeen(message.chat.id) == message.chat.id:` -  здесь ошибка, посмотрите что у вас возвращает функция и с чем вы сравниваете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так (немного подправил ваш код)

```
def firstSeen(get_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    db_worker = conn.cursor()
    db_worker.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=?", (get_id,))
    rez = db_worker.fetchall()

    if not rez:
        print('Добавил в базу')
        addUser(get_id)
        return True
    else:
        print('Уже в базе')
        return False


def addUser(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    db_worker = conn.cursor()
    db_worker.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES ({},'{}')".format(user_id, "true"))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def on_start(message):
    if not firstSeen(message.chat.id):
        print('--- Вы вернулись!')
    else:
        print('=== Вас нет в базе')
```

Comment: господи, часа 4 бился. Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @VovaKazanovsky, пожалуйста ) Примите ответ, если помогло